# How to send interrupt signal to a thread from other thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have two threads using instance of same class, which is acting as monitor. For example Thread1 and Thread2 using same instance of class ABC 'o'.

Now there is synchronized method doProcess() in class ABC which is being called by both threads. I have some condition in doProcess(), due to which first thread is in wait() state. Now when second thread went inside doProcess(), there is condition which tells it to terminate the whole processing.

One solution is to notify first thread and update some flag to tell it that don't block again and complete.

What I was thinking, can I send any signal from my monitor object 'o' (just like notify and notifyAll), to all waiting threads to interrupt and terminate?

EDITED First Solution:

```
    sync doProcess()
    {
        while( you are thread1 and !flag )
        {
           wait();  //line 3
        }
        if( you are thread2)
        {
           flag = true;
           notifyAll(); //can i send send any interrupt signal to terminate all threads in line 3 itself;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you notify the first thread without `o.notify()`?

Comment: @user6690200 You are correct, notify by monitor object.

Comment: I mean, what is the difference between `One solution is to notify....` and `What I was thinking....`, can you add some code to explain it?

Comment: @user6690200 see me edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The method is .interrupt()
This will throw and InterruptedException in the receiving thread, which should be handled in the run() method.
You'll still need to set the flag on the running thread, as the InterruptedException will not happen if the thread isn't blocking.

Comment: For calling .interrupt()  we need the object of that particular thread. But I am thinking to send signal to all waiting threads without knowing about how many threads are waiting, just like notifyAll()

Comment: Yes that is one way but I don't want to know about active threads. What I am seeking, some sort of signal through monitor.